# How to convert wet/dry to dry mode?

Tags: installation, vacuum

I have a previously-owned wet/dry ShopVac that I have only used for its wet mode (basement floods a lot). I now want to "*switch it over*" to its dry mode for the first time ever:

[image]
[image]

Not sure if it helps/matters, but the diameter of the black plastic protusion hanging down underneath the top-part is 5 1/2".

My question: what specific part(s) do I need to buy so that this will work in *dry mode* (and pick up debris and dust), and how do I install them?

Comment: Never had one, but was under the impression that wet/dry just meant it could suck saw dust and water, depending what you put the hose in.

Comment: Although I would _love_ to find out that is the case (truly!) I don't believe it is, as when I googled this question it comes up with a wide array of different filters, filter retainers and other parts...none of which seem standardized/generic or that would fit my particular model.

Comment: @crip659 A typical shop vac (of any brand) has two places you can place the hose - one for vacuuming and the other for blowing. The difference for wet vs. dry is "filter in" = "dry" (to catch the dust so it doesn't blow back out) and "filter out" = "wet" (so that the filter doesn't get ruined by the water).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the only difference between wet and dry mode is a filter.  Typical paper filters don't do well after getting wet so they need to be removed.

The only thing you should need is a new filter, and maybe a cap used to retain the filter.  I've never had that exact brand so I'm not sure how the filter is held in place.

ShopVac is one of the oldest companies making these vacs and their [website](https://www.shopvac.com/products/filterFinder.aspx) has a filter finder where you can enter in the model number.  Once you find the filter number you can find it for purchase locally or on your favorite site.  There's bound to be aftermarket versions as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JPhi618 (+1) - when I google "ShopVac filter" I get a huge amount of different results that are difficult to make sense of. Some look like cylindrical HEPA filters, others are foam sleeves. Some have "retainer caps" and others don't. So maybe I should be asking: how do I figure out my _exact_ ShopVac model and how do I use that information to find out what exact part(s) I need?

Comment: The model number is typically close to the plug or motor where the required electrical information is.  Foam filters are for wet mode, the pleated paper filters are what you want.  The [ShopVac](https://www.shopvac.com/products/filterFinder.aspx) website has a filter finder that can help.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup, Edited answer with more information and model number location from the ShopVac website.

Comment: Thank you I was able to locate my model number, search for it on their site and locate what part at my local hardware store to pick up. All set, thanks again!